# C#. Strange behavior of double

Tags: c#, double

Here is the code which made me post this question.

```
// int integer;
// int fraction;


// double arg = 110.1;

this.integer = (int)(arg);
this.fraction = (int)((arg - this.integer) * 100);
```

The variable `integer` is getting `110`. That's OK.

The variable `fraction` is getting `9`, however I am expecting `10`.

**What is wrong?**

---

**Update**

It seems I have discovered that the source of the problem is subtraction

`arg - this.integer`

Its result is `0.099999999999994316`.

Now I am wondering how I should correctly subtract so that the result was `0.1`.

Comment: Use decimal type as stated in the answers to get 0.1 when doing the subtraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using `double`, precision gets rounded, if you want it to be `10`  use `decimal` type:

check the following:

```
int integer;
int fraction;


decimal arg = 110.1M;
integer = (int)(arg);
decimal diff = arg - integer;
decimal multiply = diff * 100;
fraction = (int)multiply;//output will be 10 as you expect
```

Comment: I guess `double` should be discarded from .NET. Its nothing but a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 5):

You have this:

```
fraction = (int)((110.1 - 110) * 100);
```

The inner part `((110.1 - 110) * 100)`, will be 9.999999

When you cast it to `int`, it will be round off to 9

This is because of "floating point" ([see here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx)) limitations:

> Computers always need some way of representing data, and ultimately
>   those representations will always boil down to binary (0s and 1s).
>   Integers are easy to represent, but non-integers are a bit more
>   tricky. Consider the following var:
>
> ```
> double x = 0.1d;
> ```
>
> The variable x will actually store the **closest available double** to
>   that value. When you understand this, it becomes obvious why some
>   calculations seem to be "wrong".
>
> If you were asked to add a third to a third, but could only use 3
>   decimal places, you'd get the "wrong" answer: the closest you could
>   get to a third is 0.333, and adding two of those together gives 0.666,
>   rather than 0.667 (which is closer to the exact value of two thirds).

**Update:**
In financial applications or where the numbers are so important to be exact, you can use [**`decimal`**](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) data type:

```
(int)((110.1m - 110) * 100)  //will be 10   (m is decimal symbol)
```

or:

```
 decimal arg = 110.1m;
 int integer = (int)(arg); //110
 decimal fraction = (int)((arg - integer) * 100); //will be 10
```